# Invoke function from bash heredoc

Tags: linux, bash, unix, heredoc

I am invoking a function from a heredoc that clones a repository. But the repository is cloned on local machine, not remote which is where I want it. The script is executed on local machine.

```
_git_clone() {
    git clone myrepo
    git fetch --all --tags
}

ssh myserver <<EOF
    echo $(_git_clone)
EOF
```

Problem 2) `git fetch` only prints "Fetching origin" to the console instead of entire fetch log. How can we make that command print full log to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to transfer the code *verbatim* to the other server to run it there. A heredoc with an unquoted starting delimiter works similarly to a double quoted string, which means any command substitutions like the one you have running *before* the resulting string is passed to the remote server. You can solve this by putting the function definition inside the heredoc and single quoting the starting delimiter:

```sh
ssh myserver <<'EOF'
_git_clone() {
    git clone myrepo
    git fetch --all --tags
}
echo $(_git_clone)
EOF
```

Alternatively you can define the function locally but then substitute its definition within the heredoc:

```sh
_git_clone() {
    git clone myrepo
    git fetch --all --tags
}

ssh myserver <<EOF
$(declare -f _git_clone)
EOF
```

Comment: I just tried option 2, and I'm getting this: -bash: line 2: _git_clone: command not found

Comment: You need to leave the delimiter unquoted to use the second option. Otherwise it tries to run that function on the other host, where it has not been defined.

Comment: ok yes i meant to run it on other host that's why i added the quotes. if i remove them it works, but then clones it to the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of a *here* document are evaluated locally, just like a string enclosed in double quotes. To avoid this behavior, you need to "quote" the *here* document, like this:

```
ssh myserver <<'EOF'
  echo $(_git_clone)
EOF
```

Of course, this still won't work because you've define the `_git_clone` function locally, so on the remote system you'll simply see `bash: _git_clone: command not found...`. If you want the function to be visible remotely, it needs to go into your *here* document:

```
ssh myserver <<'EOF'
    _git_clone() {
        git clone myrepo
        git fetch --all --tags
    }

    echo $(_git_clone)
EOF
```

But that seems unnecessarily complex; you might as well just do this:

```
ssh myserver <<EOF
    git clone myrepo
    git fetch --all --tags
EOF
```

---

The relevant section of the `bash` man page on *here* document syntax is in the "Here Documents" section, which reads:

> The format of here-documents is as follows:
>
> ```
> <<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter expansion, command substitution, pathname expansion, or
> arithmetic expansion is performed on word. **If any characters in word
> are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word,
> and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.**

I've emphasized the key information.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, this is what solved my problem using idea from i0b0's answer:

```
_git_clone() {
    git clone myrepo
    git fetch --all --tags
}

ssh myserver <<EOF
    $(declare -f _git_clone)
    _git_clone
EOF
```

So the fix was to declare the function inside heredoc and then move the invocation out of command substitution.